# How do I make an application's window span the whole width/height of my screen?

Tags: window-manager, macos

I want to make an application use the whole width or height of my screen without having to drag the bottom/right sides to the edge of the screen. I also want to do this for the bottom right corner (as in, I want to make it go to the bottom right corner). Any cool tips that'll let me do this?

Comment: There's already an app that does that. It's called [Moom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is actually a cool way to do this on macOS Sierra! Just **double click** the bottom/right/bottom right of the window when the cursor turns into a resize cursor, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You can just click on the green 'Maximize' button of any window.  Doing this will make the window expand to the entire height & width of the screen.  It will work on most windows if they are designed to use the full screen.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25072?locale=en_US

Comment: The problem with this is that the window goes into full screen. The poster just wanted the window to expand to the bottom/right sides of the screen, not to go into complete full screen and take up another desktop space.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  OP states "I want to make an application use the whole width or height of my screen" and currently must drag the window to make it do this.  Using the Maximize button does this automatically.  If the OP wants to edit the question to make their desired outcome clearer, that would help us provide better answers.

Comment: I contest, because I *am* OP.

Comment: however, I will mark your answer as correct because it seems like no one finds my answer… useful. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Don't jump at the first answer that might be about right - wait a day or three to see if you get one that's exactly right. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Especially in this scenario where there are at least **three** possibilities [4 on Sierra] & the one you possibly wanted hasn't been suggested yet.

Comment: If this is not the correct answer, I recommend editing your question to make sure it states exactly the functionality you're looking for and what you've already tried.  See [ask] for how to ask a good question.